# Html5/CSS3 resize layout can't work fine

Tags: html, css

When I adjust the width of the window

I want to A B C Block sequentially arranged vertically down,

I tried for a long time, may I ask how to solve, thank you help
like below ....

A

B

C

```css
div#menu {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
}
div#navigation {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #A9F5A9;
  height: 495px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 250px;
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 31%;
}
div#content {
  height: 495px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #F2F5A9;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 500px;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-right: 33%;
}
#wrapper {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -33%;
}
div#footer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #81F7F3;
  color: #000;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  clear: both;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="content">A</div>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">B</div>
    <div id="footer">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you thought about using media queries?

Comment: I searched, but could not find my needs, it will ask

Comment: Thank you for your presentation found in the Media Queries

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try this one

```
div#menu {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: It would help to explain why table-row is a good candidate for this desired result

Comment: His requirment is to show a,b,c vertcal .If we use table-row we can easly achieve it

Comment: Imagine your audience is somebody that doesn't know CSS very well, but has heard of CSS floats, table styling and actual HTML tables.  Why didn't you choose one of those other methods?  How does the OP's requirement of 'When I adjust the width of the window' affect your answer?  Those are the explanations I'd be looking for if I was reading this question and I had a similar problem.